# How to invoke a generic method with weak-typed parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've got a generic interface and bunch of classes which implement it. Here is a greatly simplified example:

```
interface IPrinter<in T>
{
    void Print(T args);
}

class IntPrinter : IPrinter<int>
{
    public void Print(int args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is int: " +args);
    }
}

class StringPrinter : IPrinter<string>
{
    public void Print(string args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is string: " + args);
    }
}
```

I also have a dictionary of those classes with generic argument's type as a key (I actually use reflection to populate it):

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> Printers 
    = new Dictionary<Type, object>
        {
            {typeof (int), new IntPrinter()},
            {typeof (string), new StringPrinter()}
        };
```

Now I recive an instance of `List<object>` as an input, which contains a bunch of parameters of arbitrary type. For each parameter I want to pick the object, which implement an appropriate interface and call the print method. I am not sure how to implement that.

```
var args = new List<object> {1, "2"};
foreach (var arg in args)
{
    var printer = Printers[arg.GetType()];
    //how do I implement this method so it calls ((IPrinter<T>)printer).Print((T)arg)?
    Print(printer, arg); 
}
```

I have tried

1. Reflection. It works, but well... its reflection. I am looking for other ways to do it.

   ```
   private void Print(object printer, object arg)
   {
       printer.GetType().GetMethod("Print").Invoke(printer, new[] {arg});
   }
   ```
2. Dynamic. A lot cleaner than reflection and usually faster. But for some reason it throws an exception if I use it with a type, which is `private` relative to executing assembly. Is this a known limitation of dynamic objects?

   ```
   private void Print(dynamic printer, dynamic arg)
   {
       printer.Print(arg);
   }
   ```
3. Delegate. I was trying to use `CreateDelegate` method to create a some kind of weak-typed delegate from `MethodInfo` but i completely failed at that. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to share the solution which I ended up using. It utilizes two facts:

1. You can easily cast to `T` inside `Generic<T>` class.
2. You can easily (*cough*`CreateDelegate`*cough*) construct `Generic<T>` class using `typeof(T)` variable.

LinqPad sample:

```
interface IPrinter<in T>
{
    void Print(T args);
}

class IntPrinter : IPrinter<int>
{
    public void Print(int args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is int: " +args);
    }
}

class StringPrinter : IPrinter<string>
{
    public void Print(string args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is string: " + args);
    }
}

interface IPrintInvoker
{
    void Print(object printer, object args);
}

class PrintInvoker<T> : IPrintInvoker
{
    public void Print(object printer, object args)
    {
         ((IPrinter<T>)printer).Print((T)args);
    }
}

private readonly Dictionary<Type, IPrintInvoker> Invokers = new Dictionary<Type, IPrintInvoker>();

private void Print(object printer, object arg)
{
     var type = arg.GetType();
    IPrintInvoker invoker;
    if (!Invokers.TryGetValue(type, out invoker))
    {
        var invokerType = typeof(PrintInvoker<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        Invokers[type] = invoker = (IPrintInvoker)Activator.CreateInstance(invokerType );
    }
    invoker.Print(printer, arg);
}

void Main()
{
   var printer1 = new IntPrinter();
   var printer2 = new StringPrinter();
   Print(printer1, 1);
   Print(printer1, 2);
   Print(printer2, "asfasfasf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might already know that method with this signature: `void GenericMethod<T>(T arg)` would be translated to something like: `void __GenericMethod(Type typeArg1, object argument)` after first call for a class type argument (for structures you'll generate one for each struct).

Think about it. Why do we need generics at all? Why not to simply have:

```
interface IPrinter
{
    void Print(object args);
}
```

Or even...

```
interface IAnything
{
    void Do(object args);
}
```

The answer is: **compile-time** feature of C# - type-safety. We need it to avoid combining not compatible components accidentally. You don't want your `IntPrinter` to receive a `string` somehow. Lucky if you'll get an exception, but what if not?

So, using this feature is good and helps us to detect error at compile-time. But what are you doing by collecting your `Printers` dictionary? **You're loosing type-safety.** If you'll make a mistake with types somewhere, you'll experience an exception or another strange behaviour of your program at runtime.

I would propose you two alternatives:

- make `IPrinter` not type safe
- keep it generic, but don't loose type-safety while using it

Comment: Thx. I don't want to make interface non-generic because of the reason you've mentioned: I will have to pass and somehow handle `string` arguments inside objects, which are not supposed to deal with strings (such as `IntPrinter`). And for now, sadly, I don't see, how can I keep the type-safety.

Comment: IL supports generics natively so the method would be compiled as shown in C#.  The runtime would record a difference signature for each different type you pass to the generic but the method reference would be like `void GenericMethod(int arg)` and not `void GenericMethod(Type type, object arg)`

Answer (score -1):

Would this help?

```
private void Print<T, TArgs>(T printer, TArgs arg) where T : IPrinter<TArgs>
{
    printer.Print(arg);
}
```

Comment: I think it would not compile. I also don't have a non-generic `IPrinter` interface.

Comment: Woops didnt notice that, what about now?

Comment: I have two `object`s as input (see `foreach` loop in my question). How would I call your method?

Comment: `Print(printer, arg);` exactly as you have it written

Comment: It won't compile without some kind of cast.

Comment: cast where? here? `((T)printer).Print((TArgs)arg);`